# How to implement a 2-dimensional array of struct in C

Tags: c, struct, multidimensional-array

I'm currently trying to understand how to implement a 2-dimensional array of struct in C. My code is crashing all the time and I'm really about to let it end like all my approaches getting firm to C: garbage. This is what I got:

```
typedef struct {
    int i;
} test;

test* t[20][20];
*t = (test*) malloc(sizeof(test) * 20 * 20);
```

My glorious error:

> error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct test *[20]’ from type ‘struct test *’

Do I have to allocate the memory seperately for every 2nd dimension? I'm getting nuts. It should be so simple. One day I will build a time-machine and magnetize some c-compiler-floppies...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
typedef struct {
    int i;
} test;

test t[20][20];
```

That will declare a 2-dimensional array of `test` of size 20 x 20. There's no need to use malloc.

If you want to dynamically allocate your array you can do this:

```
// in a function of course
test **t = (test **)malloc(20 * sizeof(test *));
for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    t[i] = (test *)malloc(20 * sizeof(test));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 11):

```
test **t;

t = (test **)malloc(sizeof(test *) * 20);
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
   t[i] = (test *)malloc(sizeof(test) * 20);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Other answers show how to fix it but they don't explain why. As the compiler hinted, the type of `t` in your original example is actually `test *[20]` which is why your cast to `test *` wasn't enough.

In C, the name of an array T of dimension N is actually of type `*T[dim0][dim1]...[dimN-1]`. Fun.

Answer (score 4):

From my observation, you may not know exactly what you want and confuse on the struct and pointer arithmetic. Please go through the following 2 possibilities.

1) A two dimensional array with each element has a pointer to `test`. 
In this case the **memory of all the pointers to `test`s** are already statically **allocated**. 
But, the **memory of the real `test`s**  are not ready. 
In this case you must fill in the  `test [i][j]` one by one.

Each of the `test` is discrete in the memory and you have the advantage of create or destroy them individually dynamically.

```
typedef struct {
    int i;
} test;

test* t[20][20]; 
/* or instead of statically allocated the memory of all the pointers to tests
   you can do the following to dynamically allocate the memory
   test ***t;
   t = (test***)malloc(sizeof(test *) * 20 * 20);
*/ 

for (int i=0; i < 20; i++){
   for (int j=0; j < 20; j++){
      t[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(test));
   }
}
```

2)  A two dimensional array with each element is a `test`. 
In this case the **memory of all the `test`s** are already **allocated**. 
Also, the **memory of the real `test`s**  are ready to use without extra preparation.

All of the `test`s are continuous in the memory as a big block and is always there. This mean that you may waste a chunk of memory if you only need all `test`s at certain peak time and most of the time you only use a few of them.

```
typedef struct {
    int i;
} test;

test t[20][20]; 
/* or instead of statically allocated the memory of all tests
   you can do the following to dynamically allocate the memory
   test **t;
   t = (test**)malloc(sizeof(test) * 20 * 20);
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, as long as your inner dimension size is constant, you can allocate a variable number of counts of that inner dimension

```
int n = ...;
test (*t)[20] = malloc(sizeof (*t) * n);
t[0 .. (n-1)][0 .. 19] = ...;
```