# Assigning values to an array of struct (or class) behavior

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

From Java I'm used that I can do this:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public int field1;
}

SomeClass[] data = new SomeClass[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    data[i] = new SomeClass(); 
    SomeClass d = data[i];
    d.field1 = 10;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    SomeClass d = data[i];
    System.out.println("Value of data [" + i + "] is [" + d.field1 + "]");
}
```

And this will work fine, printing:

```
Value of data [0] is [10]
Value of data [1] is [10]
... etc
```

So in Java you first create the Array, which has by default all null values, and then in the first loop I create a new SomeClass and assign it to a slot in the array. If you don't do this you get a NullPointerException.

All fine.

**The question:**
I try to do the same in C++. I have one failing and one working example. But I am unsure *why it works* (or does not work, depending what example you pick). Can anyone elaborate?

First, the failing code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    MyClass data[10];
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        MyClass d = data[y];
        cout << "INITIALLY (garbage): [" << d.field1 << ", " << d.field2 << "] " << endl;
        // assign values
        d.field1 = 2;
        d.field2 = 3;
    }

    // print out data of first 10
    cout << "Printing out data after initialization" << endl;
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        MyClass d = data[y];
        cout << "[" << d.field1 << ", " << d.field2 << "] " << endl;
    }
}
```

So If i understand correctly, according to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275381/how-to-implement-a-2-dimensional-array-of-struct-in-c/3275389#3275389) I can create an array of a Struct like I do in the above code.

What I noticed is that if I do not use:

```
MyClass d = data[y];
d.field1 = 2;
d.field2 = 3;
```

But instead I do:

```
data[y].field1 = 2;
data[y].field2 = 3;
```

It does work.

However, if I insist on using a separate value, I can still make it work by doing this:

```
MyClass * d = &data[y];
d->field1 = 2;
d->field2 = 3;
```

I do not change anything in printing the output. And the above works.

So, something clearly is different when using a pointer to data[y]. I cannot found a clear answer on this though. Anyone able to explain why?

If this question is a duplicate, sorry for that, I could not find a real answer on the 
"why" part. Code snippets are not always enough for me ;)

PPS: I am aware that I am not allocating this array in the heap. Bonus points for touching that subject to compare to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, an object is a *region of storage* - that is, an area of memory.  Variables denote objects directly, unless they are explicitly qualified as pointers or references to existing objects.

When you write:

```
MyClass d = data[y];
```

you are *declaring* a variable of type `MyClass`, *defining* it as denoting an object on the stack, and *initialising* it from the object `data[y]`; `d` and `data[y]` are separate objects so modifying `d` will not affect `data[y]`.

You want to write:

```
MyClass &d = data[y];
        ^--- here
```

The ampersand `&` denotes `d` as a *reference* to the object `data[y]`, so as long as an object continues to exist within the region of storage that `data[y]` originally denoted (i.e. at that address), you can use `d` to modify that object.

Using a pointer is similar, but because pointers can be reseated to point to a different object you must use indirection syntax (`*` or `->`) to denote the object they point to.

Comment: Wow thanks a bunch! Really clear answer. Do you have any further reference for me to get a better understanding of these behaviours? For example, this is a one dimensional array. What If I'd like to have a two dimensional array? In Java things are just much easier to grasp. But I insist on doing this in C++. Again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You are making a copy here:

```
MyClass d = data[y];
```

Modifications to `d` have no impact on `data[y]`.

Take a reference instead:

```
MyClass& d = data[y];
```

Now `d` refers to the element `data[y]`. Note that in C++ a reference behaves like an alias. You cannot re-assign it. For example

```
d = someMyClassInstance;
```

will have the effect of assigning the value of `someMyClassInstance` to `data[y]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not realize I was creating a copy. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
    MyClass d = data[y];
    d.field1 = 2;
    d.field2 = 3;
```

Has no effect because `d` is now a copy of `data[y]`.  If you said `MyClass& d` instead, you'd have a (non-const) reference, which you could modify and then observe those changes in `data`.